# Targeting rules for Beacons are not working

Tags: rules, targeting, google-beacon-platform

I have about 50 beacons (eddystone, with the google dashboard) and I programmed them all to change their message daily, however more than 2/3 of them just fire off the message any day or time they like which is a problem since the product they are messaging for are only free on that certain day that I had programmed them to send the message.

And yes, I have gone back in and made certain they were programmed correctly, and they were. I have used targeting rules for just the correct day of the week (M-S), but they will fire any day of the week. I have also tried the specific day of the month, but they fire any time they like. I have also tried to specify the time, but again, they just fire at will so I am blowing through literally thousands of clicks that don't convert because what the person wanted simply isn't available at the URL they clicked on.

Is there any way to actually have the targeting rules apply and stick? 100% of the time?

For example I have an ad I only want to run on wednesday (because the product will be free on that day on Amazon), so I place a target rule for just Wednesday (day 3 per dashboard). Yet on Monday and Tuesday I get hundreds of clicks on my bit.ly that is specific to that individual beacon. The same goes for if I put the exact date. It still fires days ahead of time.

I am trying to get a workflow so that I can do a week's worth of promos to all the beacons ahead of time, but if they fire off early, that is obviously counter-productive.

Please help! :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I think there are couple things here you might have missed. 
The thousands of clicks you are getting on your bit.ly link might not be actual users rather Google crawler. If all the links are coming from California, then they are most likely bot clicks.

The timer targeting works based on your phone date-time. So the targeting would work perfectly fine if your phone time is correct. This means, different people across timezones would get your message at "their" time of the targeted message. I hope this makes sense.
If this is confusing, you can try some management platforms like [Estimote here&now](https://estimote.com), [Blueacon.io](https://blueacon.io) & [Beaconcontrol.io](https://beaconcontrol.io)